# Problema no application.properties do Spring boot

Tags: java, spring

Esse é meu arquivo no application.properties

```
  ###############################################################################
    # PORTA
    ###############################################################################
    
    server.port=8100
    
    ###############################################################################
    # BANCO DE DADOS
    ###############################################################################
    
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://194.168.1.30:1445;DatabaseName=DB_TREINAMENTO_JAVA
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password=123
    
    ###############################################################################
    # LIQUIBASE
    ###############################################################################
    
    spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/master.xml
    spring.liquibase.default-schema=dbo
    
    ###############################################################################
    # CONFIGURACOEES SPRING
    ###############################################################################
    
    spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
    spring.jpa.database=SQL_SERVER
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
    
    ###############################################################################
    # CONFIGURAÇÕES ARQUIVOS - UPLOAD
    ###############################################################################
    
    spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
    spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
    spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
    spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
    
    file.upload-dir=/documentos/UploadDir
```

E ele esta gerando essa exception no momento que eu rodo o meu projeto...

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Não estou conseguindo entender a raiz do problema deste projeto.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 4):

Certifique que a dependência do `driver` de conexão com o banco está no seu projeto.

No seu caso seria o driver para o `SQLServer`.

Caso seja maven, veja se tem:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Caso seja gradle, seria:

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifica se as dependências estão importadas corretamente. Já tive o mesmo erro por conta de uma importação errada

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).